# how can i set the value checked in ListPreference

Tags: android, checked, listpreference

I have some problems with using ListPreference, when i set the value with useing ListPreference.setEntries() and ListPreference.setEntryValues() , then  the value was  set ,but is was not checked  , i tried the ListPreference.setEnabled(true) and ListPreference.setSelectable(true), but it was about the ListPreference , not the values in ListPreference,  any method to make it checked with coding after i set the value?

thanks

Answer (score 11):

To default the selected item in a `listPreference`, use `setValueIndex`